# loop for adding prime numbers in c++

Tags: c++, addition

here is a loop that is supposed to add prime numbers only and ignore non prime numbers but it is not working properly ,my skills are pretty basic , so please try to simplify your answers as much as possible,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 0, a = 0, sum = 0;

    cin >> n;

    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        cin >> a;
        if (a == 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (a == 2 || a == 3)
        {
            sum += a;
        }
        if (a % 2 == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        for (int i = 3; i < a; i++)
        {
            if (a % i != 0)
            {
                sum += a;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the role of `a`. I guess it should be `j`instead. Moreover, the test "prime or not" should be terminated at the end of the `for (int i = ...)` loop, not inside. Better: implement and use a function `bool isprime (int a) {...}`

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? If you didn't, please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer using this function instead. You should add `cmath` library:

```
bool isPrime(int number) {
    if (number <= 1)
        return false;

    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(number); i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

But if you want to continue with your code, after checking `a == 2 || a == 3` you should `continue`. And last part before for loop you should define some boolean like `bool isPrime = true`. Then if its finds a divider you should assing it to `false` and `break`.

Your full code should be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 0, a = 0, sum = 0;

    cin >> n;

    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        cin >> a;
        if (a == 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (a == 2 || a == 3)
        {
            sum += a;
            continue;
        }
        if (a % 2 == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        bool isPrime = true;
        for (int i = 3; i < a; i++)
        {
            if (a % i == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            sum += a;
        }
    }
    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the role of 'a' ? Prime test should be on 'j' simply.

Comment: I think 'n' is the number of integers to test and 'a' is the integer to add to sum if prime.

Comment: It seems that the goal is to sum the prime numbers, according to the question. Ambiguity here. Sarah Ali could clarify it.